# Strange numbers in db2top

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11

I occasionally use db2top to get a quick overview of what is happening. I think I've seen it before but not reflected over it, but today I noticed that there are some strange numbers in the Tables view. As an example for a certain table:

```
Delta RowsRead/s:  202M-b872M-b922
Data Pages      :  122M-b962
```

Not sure what to make out of that. At first I thought it was some kind of wrapping effect due to my terminal, but I maximized it, and restarted db2top but the numbers remain in that format. Anyone know how to interpret those numbers?

And yes, I'm aware that the use of db2top is discouraged, but I'm still curious about why those type of numbers occur and what to make out of them.

#> db2level
... DB2 code release "SQL11058" with level
identifier "0609010F" "DB2 v11.5.8.0"

#> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa)

The "problem" occurs in other places as well (Database, Bufferpool, etc)

Comment: What is the shell's codepage? Any cryptomining in the background...? ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think you are onto something. I switched to another user with a different locale and there it seems to work. I'll check exactly what made the difference

Comment: LANG was sv_SE.utf8. export LANG=en_US.utf8 solved the issue. If you add an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the locale / codepage for the shell in which db2top is running. It might be that characters are not mapped correctly. You might want to try to set

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

to see if it works correctly. If it does, it is the codepage...

Note that LANG is used as a substitute for any unset LC_*. IF LC_ALL is set it may not help to update LANG, in that case update LC_ALL to solve the issue

Comment: I discovered that if LC_ALL is set to something it does not help to update LANG. I added some info about that to your answer. Feel free to revert it if you feel that it is misleading